# Apache Camel - What is most Camel way to send errors and good object simultaneously from Component Endpoint?

Tags: apache-camel

Edit: To be specific I think I am asking for an elegant way to specify 2 endpoints, which I want to send 2 different exchanges from an input of 1 exchange.

I know Camel 'can' do this - but I only have inelegant methods involving sending an object which contains both types to a multicast() and processors on each section removing

---

I expect there to be potentially multiple error messages with source objects attached. I could just throw them each as exceptions, but this feels incorrect. I'm wondering what the 'correct' approach might be. I almost just want to be able to specify an error endpoint as a target for my component

Currently I have

```
camel.addComponent( "my", new MyComponent() )


from( some source ) 
... processing // Lists of input objects as body of in
... onException()
.to( "my:endpoint" )
```

MyComponent <-- MyEndpoint <-- MyProducer

I want to process the items in each List object that arrives at MyProducer. I process the elements and send failing items out to one endpoint, and good items out to an endpoint

I do not see a good / elegant way of achieving this. If it was single elements (i.e. not collection) I can just throw an exception and catch it in an onException stream.

But I really want to be able to take items, and separate good items and send them one way, and bad items and send them another.

In other words, I want to simultaneously send 2 different messages to 2 different endpoints from the same input from an Endpoint. (The endpoint isn't actually so important here, it is juts I am writing one, it could be any Processor).

I know I could make a decomposable object with good and bad items on it, then multicast and process each good and bad section out on different pieces, but I really would like a succinct reusable mechanism (e.g. built into a Processor or endpoint)

Comment: You say that "I do not see a good / elegant way of achieving this, for single elements" but surely a single element is just a collection with one element.  How can you send a single message to both a failed and success end point? Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: It's just badly written, I should have put a semicolon rather than a comma . It was meant to be a pause

Comment: rewritten now to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

In Camel the stuff between the from() and the to() are an `Exchange` which is treated as a single message. The component should just be a factory for `Endpoint` instances, which either creates or sends exchanges. It shouldn't be processing the message (which is what it sounds like here) so there's not really a concept of of errors or good objects, that's for the `Route` and the `Processors`/`Beans` to decide.

If you want to do it all within a single exchange then you can simply have your processor add 2 lists to exchange properties and route them based on the contents.

```
from("direct:somesource")
   .process(new Processor() {
       public void process(Exchange exchange) {
           // get contents, 
           // turn it into a list 
           // 
           List<Object> worked = new ArrayList<>();
           List<Object> failed = new ArrayList<>();
           for (Object o : listFromBody) {
              try {
                  // do work
                  worked.add(o);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  failed.add(o)
              }
           }
           exchange.getIn().setProperty("worked", worked);
           exchange.getIn().setProperty("failed", failed);
       }
    };)
   .choice()
            .when(header("failed").isNotEqualTo(null)) // might be a better way to do this, I've not got the IDE open 
                .process(turnFailedHeaderIntoMessageBody)
                .to("direct:errorQueue")
            .otherwise()
                .process(turnWorkedHeaderIntoMessageBody)
                .to("direct:workedQueue");
```

However this is not a good camel pattern. It's messy and tries to treat the properties as different messages which is contrary to how camel works. From the route's perspective the exchange is an atomic unit, so if you need to break the message up, it's usual to route the contents of the Exchange to be processed as an `Exchange` by a different route.

I personally would split the list into separate exchanges and process them individually like this:

```
from("direct:somesource")
   .split(body())
   .to("direct:processIndividualMessage");  


from("direct:direct:processIndividualMessage")  
    .doTry()
        .process(myProcessor)
        .to("direct:goodQueue")
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
        .to("direct:errorQueue")
    .end()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all depends on your data model. But Camel has no limitations in this regards, you certainly achieve this. I can clarify if you have any specific question.